# how to open mypage.com/link-page in htaccess without affect other page?

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, friendly-url

I have this code to open `mywebsite.com/any-post-name` :

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ home.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

the problem is, if anyone types: mywebsite.com/any-post-name`/` the page wont open.
So I add:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_/-]+)$ home.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

now, every other page goes to home.php too, for example, I have category:
mypage.com/category/name-category -> will come to home.php

```
RewriteRule ^category/([^(.*)].+)/(\d+)/?$ category.php?categoria=$1&id=$2
```

how to solve this?

Comment: try `home.php$` instead of `home.php?id=$1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the `/` in the character class allows it multiple times because of the quantifier (`+`). If you move that to the end of the regex and make it optional it should work for you.

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/jA0oZ1/3

or

```
^([^/]+)/?$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/jA0oZ1/4

Comment: thank you very much! I have a page calls /category/ to open allcategories.php and it matches with this regex... how can I solve this? RewriteRule ^category/?$ allcategories.php put if before your regex is a good idea?

Comment: I would make a more structured URL in that case, otherwise you're going to have to write a rule for every root page (that shouldn't be directed to the `home.php` page. A possible untested solution to that could be `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^category/?$` before the `rewrite`.